# Boot Windows 10 from RAID0

Tags: multi-boot, raid, bootloader

I had a Windows 10 machine with Auros Z390 Pro mainbard, SATA SSD system disk and RAID0 with two M2 disks and successfully installed seconds clean Windows 10 on the RAID.

Now when I start my machine I see a blue boot menu where I select old or new Windows 10 installations.

`msconfig` command on new Windows 10 displays the following:

[image]

where C: is RAID and D: is SATA drive.

Now I need to unplug old SATA drive, but can't do this because my machine stops booting after that.

And I do not have an options in BIOS to select my RAID as a boot drive:

[image]

As far as I can guess, Windows Boot Manager runs from my old SATA drive (D:).

See [my blog post](https://developernote.com/2024/03/configuring-raid-on-auros-z390-mainboard/) for more info on how I configured RAID0.